# Center of a compact group

Tags: lie-groups

Suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group, we know the center of $G$ is a compact Abelian subgroup, so it must be isomorphic to a direct product of finite abelian subgroup and a torus.

Now suppose the center is not finite (i.e the torus part of the center is not trivial), then can we split the torus out? For example, if the torus part is $S^1$, can we claim $G$ is a direct product of $S^1$ and some subgroup $H$ of $G$. I think this is true, but I am not sure.

If this is not true, can anyone provide me with an counterexample? Thank you!

Comment: you must assume that $G$ is connected; otherwise, this is obviously false. AS Bryant has said, it is false even for $U(2)$.

Comment: which is connected, and its center is connected, so I don't see why you bring up connectedness.

Comment: Right. I should have formulated my statement carefully. The original motivation comes from a trick in Knapp's book, when we use some kind of Unitarian trick to simplify the argument for Harish Chandra's $\Xi$-function. But there he assumes G is linear connected semisimple group, I just think if his argument may be useful for general real reductive group. Of course we need to assume connectedness.

Comment: @Allen; I meant to say, even f $G$ is connected, it is false. But for disconnected $G$, it is also false, by "easier" considerations

Answer (score 5):

This is not true.  Take $\mathrm{U}(2)$, for example.  It is not the direct product of its center (the matrices of the form $\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} \mathrm{I}_2$) with the simple part $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.  The point is that the center, which is an $S^1$, intersects the simple part $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ in two distinct points, $\{\pm \mathrm{I}_2\}$.

Comment: Thanks you! I think the fallacy may come from the outer automorphism in general, am I right?

Comment: Nevertheless $G$ and $Z(G)\times H$ (where $H=G/Z(G)$) have the same Lie algebra, so their universal covers coincide.

Comment: There are no outer automorphisms for SU(2).  The phenomenon of not splitting off central tori has nothing to do with outer automorphisms.

Comment: Yep, but for $SU(n)$, (n>3), the outer automorphism group comes from Dynkin Diagram. So it is not trivial, right? When I try to justity my claim, I use an exact sequence. But it is not split in general. My concern is that when we construct an homomorhism from $Z(G)$ to $Aut(G/Z(G))$, it is not necessarily an inner automorphism. Am I right?